# SQL Server 2008 + performance issues for select query with over 100k data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 20 columns in `Sample` table. It has one foreign key relationship (DID). It has 8 joins with other tables to retrieve the required data. In that we have 2 UDf fns to calculate avg and data conversions on 4 selected columns.

My main issues is daily I am getting 100k data into this table. When I am executing the procedure in SQL Query analyzer itself is taking 1 min 30 sec for 100k data. My web application tab which retrieves the data from this procedure is always running every minute to pull from latest to the last 2 days data. So if I am trying to retrieve the full list of data it is taking bit time to show it on screen.

Created nonclustered index on parameters with which I am filtering like Date, SID.. etc no performance improvement

Optimizations tried:

- Take out udf functions on procedure for avg and data conversion calculations and placed in application.But after that also couple of secs improvement not much.

`Sample` table:

```
ID--bigint -- Primary key
DID--bigint -- Foreign key  
SID--bigint -- It has reference table
SLID--bigint -- It has reference table
OD--bigint -- It has reference table
SD--bigint -- It has reference table
SKD--bigint  -- It has reference table
V1--decimal(10,2)
V2--decimal(10,2)
V3--decimal(10,2)
UC--varchar
Date--datetime
EB--bigint  -- It has reference table
UB--bigint  -- It has reference table
SSD--bigint -- It has reference table
PID--bigint -- It has reference table
```

Note: couple of fields which are not used for select not included above fyi.

All the above reference table are the used for joins in procedure to retrieve the data.

---

Query (Sample Data View):

```
SELECT 
   DH.DHID, DH.DID, D.SNo, D.Addr, D.DTID, D.DT, DH.SID, SI.CODE, DH.SLID, SL.SLoc, 
   DH.OD, O.ONumber, DH.SD, S.SName, DH.SKD, SK.SKN, 
   (CASE 
       WHEN DH.V1 IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT dbo.udfConvert(CAST(DH.V1 AS FLOAT)) ) 
       ELSE NULL END) AS V1, 
  (CASE 
       WHEN DH.V2 IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT dbo.udfConvert(CAST(DH.V2 AS FLOAT)) )  
       ELSE NULL END) AS V2, 
  (CASE 
       WHEN DH.V3 IS NOT NULL THEN (SELECT dbo.udfConvert(CAST(DH.V3 AS FLOAT)) ) 
       ELSE NULL END) AS V3, 
  (CASE 
       WHEN (DH.V1 IS NOT NULL OR DH.V2 IS NOT NULL OR DH.V3 IS NOT NULL) THEN dbo.udfConvert(CAST((ISNULL(DH.V1, 0) + ISNULL(DH.V2, 0) + ISNULL(DH.V3, 0)) / (CASE WHEN DH.V1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + CASE WHEN DH.V2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + CASE WHEN DH.V3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) AS FLOAT)) ELSE NULL END) AS AvgValue, DH.Date, DH.EB, U.UName, U.Name, DH.UB, U1.UUName, U1.Name, DH.SSD, FSIS.Status, DH.PID, P.SNo 
FROM 
   SampleTable DH 
INNER JOIN 
   qryDs D ON D.DID = DH.DID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    qrySIs SI ON SI.SID = DH.SID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    qrySLs SL ON SL.SLID = DH.SLID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    qryOs O ON O.OD = DH.OD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    qrySDs S ON S.SD = DH.SD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    qrySKs SK ON SK.SKD = DH.SKD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    qryU U ON U.UID = DH.EB 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    qryU U1 ON U1.UID = DH.UB 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    qryFSIS FSIS ON FSIS.SSD = DH.SSD 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    qryPBs P ON P.PID = DH.PID
```

---

### Executed Proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleDataInfo] <br />
@StartDate DATETIME = NULL,<br />
@EndDate DATETIME = NULL,<br />
@SName NVARCHAR(50) = NULL,<br />
@ONumber VARCHAR(100) = NULL,<br />
@Code VARCHAR(100) = NULL<br />
AS<br />
IF @StartDate IS NULL<br />
    SET @StartDate = CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE() - 1, 121 )<br />
IF @EndDate IS NULL<br />
    SET @EndDate = CONVERT( DATETIME, GETDATE() + 1, 121 )<br />
SELECT * FROM SampleDataView<br />
    WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate<br />
    AND SName = @SName<br />
    AND ONumber = @ONumber<br />
    AND Code = @Code<br />
GO
```

---

This is the usual time it take for procedure to execute such 100k data or something performance improvements I can do. Please advise

Comment: You're missing the most important thing: you're not showing us the **QUERY** you're executing!

Comment: I added the query i am using to pull all the data.Please check once and let me know

Comment: You said that you're pulling data from the last 2 days, but that filter is not represented in your query above. That filter and how you're applying it is almost the single most important piece of the puzzle and is the starting point for optimizing. Can you add it with the exact syntax?

Comment: Initially i added the view used to query the data. for that view only the filters will be added bu any how i gave the procedure used for querying the data have and look and let me know if you find any option to optimize

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a large table, called T1. If you can predetermine a subset of T1, then you can define a T2 table, which, schematically would be a copy of T1, but would contain only the smallest subset of T1, which would guarantee that all the potential records to be selected are available. Thus, T2 would be a cache of T1 and you would need to refresh it from time to time (the exact method of refreshing depends on strategy).

Example: If you have a table which stores invoices, even very old invoices and your users would select only invoices from the last 3 months, then you could create such a caching approach.

Answer (score 0):

Put an index on all 8 tables on the column(s) that you're joining on.

Comment: I added the non clustered index for all the filtered columns which is mostly reference tables fields and Date field.But i don't see much performance impact